# Sphere intersection Stuck

Tags: collision-detection

I have two spheres that are bounded by spheres for collision detection. I do not want them to intersect. My intersection works. But it gets stuck. Once the function returns true, I cannot get it out. I tried

```
collideBool = ObjectOne.Intersect(ObjectTwo);

if(collide == true)
{
    leftright = leftright;
    updown = updown;
}
else
{
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
leftright -= dt;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
leftright += dt;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
updown += dt;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
updown -= dt;
}

collide = false;
```

My sphere gets stuck. What is a way around this?

Comment: First of all, what is the engine? And by the way, you're assigning ObjectOne.Intersect return value to collideBool, but check collide. Typo?

Comment: The code inside the `if(collide == true)` statement does nothing. It sets variables equal to themselves. Perhaps, you want to push the spheres away from each other if they intersect?

Comment: So pushing them away by a very small value like 0.00001 will offset the bool value and be unnoticable? Is that the standard way of doing it? I really don't want a pool ball effect. First of all, what is the engine?

Comment: http://d3dcoder.net/ Frank Lunas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for collision against the new position and undo if it would cause a collision.

```
float oldleftright = leftright, oldupdown = updown;

if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
    leftright -= dt;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
    leftright += dt;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
    updown += dt;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
    updown -= dt;

bool collide = ObjectOne.Intersect(ObjectTwo);
if (collide)
{
    leftright = oldleftright;
    updown = oldupdown;
}
collide = false;
```